# Javascript prototype property returning undefined in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Creating image rotator using prototypal inheritance, I keep getting an error in the console displaying: TypeError: this.curPhoto is undefined
         this.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
I put this in the callback function of one of the functions used to switch the positions of the overlapping divs (stack under each other) Here is the code:

```
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='ImageRotatorOOP.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('document').ready(function() {
    setInterval('rotateImages()', 2000);
    });

    function rotateImages() {
    var imageRotator = new ImageRotator($('#photoShow'));
    if(imageRotator.nextPhoto.length == 0) {
        imageRotator.nextPhoto = imageRotator.container.children().first();
    }

    imageRotator.stackImages();
    }
    </script>

    </head>
  <body>
  <h1> Image Rotator </h1>
  <div id='photoShow'>
<div class='current'>
    <img src='images/RoyMustang.jpg' alt='Roy Mustang' />
</div>
<div>
    <img src='images/nhk.png' alt='Welcome to the NHK' />
</div>
<div>
    <img src='images/dragonball_z.jpg' alt='Dragonball Z'/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And The .js file

```
    var ImageRotator = function(container) {
this.container = container;
this.curPhoto = this.container.find('div.current');
this.nextPhoto = this.curPhoto.next('div'); 
}

ImageRotator.prototype.stackImages = function() {
    this.curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    this.nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000,      function() {
        this.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```

Here is the css file

```
   #photoShow img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;  
    }

    #photoShow div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    }

    #photoShow div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
    }

    #photoShow div.current {
    z-index: 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the animation completion function, the value of `this` will be the DOM object animating, not your `ImageRotator` object.  You can fix that issue by doing something like this:

```
ImageRotator.prototype.stackImages = function() {
    this.curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    var self = this;
    this.nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        self.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```

Note: this is a common issue with callback functions because every function call in Javascript sets a new value for `this` so unless the animation callback is specifically designed to set the value of `this` to what you want, it will be set to something else.  Saving the value into a local variable before the embedded callback is a common work-around.  You could also use `.bind()` which does something similar, but does it for you.

Here's an example using `.bind()`:

```
ImageRotator.prototype.stackImages = function() {
    this.curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    this.nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        this.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that problem up while teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this section of code:

```
ImageRotator.prototype.stackImages = function() {
    this.curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    this.nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000,      function() {
        this.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```

On the line, `this.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');`, `this` does not refer to the `ImageRotator` instance but to a jQuery object.

You can fix this by saving the value of `this` in the closure above.

```
ImageRotator.prototype.stackImages = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    this.nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000,      function() {
        that.curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
}
```